# Jquery Functions does not work on function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a jquery function which receives a parameter from it callers. Calling `split()` on the parameter throws error. Here is the function

```
function formatNairaCurrency(value) {
var formatedWithoutNaira;
var formattedAmount
//check if value is in kobo format
var splittedValue = value.split(".");//Throws error
if (splittedValue.length === 2) {
    formatedWithoutNaira = isNaN(splittedValue[0]) ? "" : splittedValue[0].toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    formattedAmount = "&#x20a6;" + formatedWithoutNaira + splittedValue[1];
} else {
    formatedWithoutNaira = isNaN(value) ? "" : value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    formattedAmount = "&#x20a6;" + formatedWithoutNaira + ".00";
}

return formattedAmount;}
```

The call `var splittedValue = value.split(".");` throws  the error `value.split is not a function`

What am I missing?

I am calling this in a `.cshtml` file. This works in another function even on the same `.js` file. The difference is that the `value` was not a parameter but a value from a text box.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `value` is a type which does not have the `split()` method. You haven't shown where you call `formatNairaCurrency` or what it's value is, so we can't really help. From the context of a currency, I would assume the value is a float, so try `value.toString().split('.')`

Comment: updated my answer to include some tools that can help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your intention correctly you are trying to use split for string. Your error could be caused by the fact that value is not string. You need to debug or throw to console 'value'.

**Edit:** For example if

value is **null**, or value is **undefinded** this would most definitely cause your error. Testing for those conditions:

```
(value === null)
(typeof value === 'undefined')
```

If your value is **number** - that would cause error too. You need to cast number to string first. You can do it by

```
var valueAsString = value.toString();
valueAsString.split('.');
```